# Is there a way for Python to make a list of values obtained in a For() function?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, email, tkinter

I am trying to read email addresses out of a file. Which are being returned in a for function. Currently this function gets me one email address at a time and only stores one value ie

`xyz@abc.com '\n' 123@abc.com '\n' 456@abc.com`

I would like to get a comma separated list of the function ie

`xyz@abc.com, 123@abc.com, 456@abc.com`

`

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import email, smtplib, ssl
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import pandas as pd
import csv
import re


# Read and store content of an excel file 
read_file = pd.read_excel ("TEST_Email_List.xlsx")
  
# Write the dataframe object into csv file
read_file.to_csv ("Emaillist.csv",  index = None, header=True)
    
# Read the csv file contenets
global reciver_email
with open('Emaillist.csv') as csv_file:
    csv=csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    # join csv data into string
    for row in csv:
        data=(', '.join(row))

        # search for email addresses
        emails = re.findall("([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.,]+)", data)

        # print list of email addresses
        for mail in emails:
            receiver_email = mail
            print(mail)
```

`

I've tried to do some join functions but seem to be stuck with carriage returns.

Comment: What does your input data look like? What is your ultimate goal? I think there is a lot of extraneous stuff going on needlessly here, not to mention lots of unnecessary imports for a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See also [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: try: `data = ', '.join([x.strip() for x in row])` or if `\n` is an item in the list `[x for x in row if x != '\n']`

Comment: The goal of the program is to take any excel sheet, find all the email addresses in it and ignore anything else that might be in it. I then need it to take all the email addresses found and string them together like so: 123@abc.com, 456@abc.com, ...

Answer (score 0):

Your data source is not obvious from your question. Please look how to make a working example for future questions.

examples:

```py
## \n is an item in the list
my_csv_output = ['xyz@abc.com', '\n', '123@abc.com', '\n', '456@abc.com']
str_list = ', '.join([x for x in my_csv_output if x != '\n'])
>>> xyz@abc.com, 123@abc.com, 456@abc.com

## the list is a string without seperation
my_csv_output = ["xyz@abc.com '\n' 123@abc.com '\n' 456@abc.com"]
str_list = ', '.join([x.replace("'", "") for x in my_csv_output.split() if x != '\n'])

## '\n is part of the items in the list
my_csv_output = ["xyz@abc.com '\n'", "123@abc.com '\n'", "456@abc.com"]
str_list = ', '.join([x.replace("'", "").strip() for x in my_csv_output])
```

A working example of your code for this would be something like:

```py
#csv=csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
csv = [
['xyz@abc.com', '\n', '123@abc.com', '\n', '456@abc.com']
['xyz@abc.com', '\n', '123@abc.com', '\n', '456@abc.com']
['xyz@abc.com', '\n', '123@abc.com', '\n', '456@abc.com']
]
# join csv data into string
for row in csv:
    data=(', '.join(row))
```